# Tshark. List all traffic between two IP's?

Tags: networking, command-line, linux-mint, wireshark, forensics

I'm learning to use Tshark. I am trying to retrieve a list of all conversations between two IP addresses using Tshark.
The two IP's are:

- 192.168.1.158
- 64.12.24.50

In Wireshark I am able to see the communication between the IP's
[image]

At the command line I issue the following command:

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap -T fields -e ip.src==192.168.1.158 -e ip.dst==64.12.24.50
```

For some reason, I'm not getting any output. I'm not sure why?

Comment: `-e` is add a field. What you're trying to do is filtering, not adding fields. Try `-R` or `-Y`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get all network traffic between `192.168.1.158|64.12.24.50`, you can run the following tshark command:

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap 'ip.addr==192.168.1.158 and ip.addr==64.12.24.50'
```

To change things up if you want to see all source traffic from your non-routable IP `192.168.1.158` and your destination aol IP address `64.12.24.50 (bos-m013a-rdr3.blue.aol.com)`, you can run the following:

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap 'ip.src==192.168.1.158 and ip.dst==64.12.24.50'
```

BTW, the `-e` field allows you to add a field to the list of fields to display if `-T` fields is selected.